# Dynamic object reference C#

Tags: c#, list, properties

I created a method Mydata to assign the new data form the list (listData). But the way I am doing this is not dynamically and I am using an if else statement to determine how many data to add and in which property it belongs. Is there a way to simplify this or make it dynamically, without using if else statement.

```
public List<Data> _newData = new List<Data>();

public void Mydata(int number, List<string> listData) {
             if (number == 1) {
              _newData.Add(new Data() {
                       variable0 = listData[0].ToString(),
                 });
             } 
             else if (number == 2) {
             _newData.Add(new Data() {
                       variable0 = listData[0].ToString(),
                       variable1 = listData[1].ToString(),
                 });    
               }
             else if (number == 3) {
             _newData.Add(new Data() {
                       variable0 = listData[0].ToString(),
                       variable1 = listData[1].ToString(),
                       variable2 = listData[2].ToString(),
                 });    
               } 


class Data
{
  public string variable1 { get; set; }
  public string variable2 { get; set; }
  public string variable3 { get; set; }
  public string variable4 { get; set; }
  ..
  public string variable10 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why not have the list as an internal of `data` and let each property just return the value of its corresponding index?

Comment: Can you explain the intent of this code? Your code for condition number == 2 and number == 3 is same. This is confusing.

Comment: Is this your actual code? There are lots of ways to avoid this sort of problem but using List<string> to pass everything around and a class with variableX names in it makes we wonder if this is an X-Y problem

Comment: This looks like the [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession) antipattern; your `data` class is just a dumb bag of primitive types and has no methods or knowledge of its contents. The solution is to put the `MyData` method inside your class and make it return the correct variables. Variable names with trailing consecutive numbers and calling `ToString()` on everything are also yellow cards.

Comment: following on from above, if this is your real code, then having variable1 to 10 is not really any different than just having a list.     the difference is just `v1` vs `l[0]`   except keeping it as a list will be simpler code for you

Comment: Also, why are you doing `.ToString()` on a `string`? This is very weird code indeed

Comment: You assign to `variable0` but don't have that in your `class Data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep the data structure the way it is (not recommended-- see comments), the obvious code simplification would be:

```
var d = new Data
{
    variable0 = listData[0];
};
if (number >= 1) d.variable1 = listData[1];
if (number >= 2) d.variable2 = listData[2];
if (number >= 3) d.variable3 = listData[3];
_newData.Add(d);
```

Comment: Your `number` counts are one off - you should assign `variable1` only if `number >= 2`, so you really need a test and assignment for `variable0`.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage. If OP ever corrects his example, I'll correct my example solution.

Answer (score -1):

The correct solution is `Data` should use a `string[]` or `List<string>` instead of separate properties. However, it can be emulated in a couple of ways.

Since C# doesn't have member references you can use delegates to set the properties:

```
public void Mydata(int number, List<string> listData) {
    var nd = new Data();
    var setters = new Action<Data,string>[] {
        (d,s) => d.variable0 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable1 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable2 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable3 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable4 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable5 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable6 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable7 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable8 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable9 = s,
        (d,s) => d.variable10 = s,
    };

    while (number-- > 0)
        setters[number](nd, listData[number]);

    _newData.Add(nd);
}
```

Alternatively, you can change `Data` to support an indexed property that returns a reference to a field though this does add a lot of overhead to every `Data1` object:

```
public class Data1 {
    public string variable0;
    public string variable1;
    public string variable2;
    public string variable3;
    public string variable4;
    public string variable5;
    public string variable6;
    public string variable7;
    public string variable8;
    public string variable9;
    public string variable10;

    public delegate ref string RefStringFunc();

    private List<RefStringFunc> refvar;

    public Data1() {
        refvar = new List<RefStringFunc>() {
            () => ref variable0,
            () => ref variable1,
            () => ref variable2,
            () => ref variable3,
            () => ref variable4,
            () => ref variable5,
            () => ref variable6,
            () => ref variable7,
            () => ref variable8,
            () => ref variable9,
            () => ref variable10,
        };
    }

    public ref string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return ref refvar[index]();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the indexed property to assign values:

```
public void Mydata1(int number, List<string> listData) {
    var nd = new Data1();

    while (number-- > 0)
        nd[number] = listData[number];

    _newData.Add(nd);
}
```

Finally, you could use Reflection, but that is really not the best way to express your intent, and not recommended (though it does offer another way to emulate member references).